# Hibernate Criteria Restriction field naming confusion

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I'm confused with the criteria Restriction field naming on Hibernate when we apply a condition. I have a database table called "User" and it contains a field called "**status_id**". I have used the eclipse hibernate tools to generate the POJOs and it created the **User** class and the property name is "**statusId**" within the class, which does not have the "_" sign.

Now I want to know in the following code, which name I have to use for the Restriction criteria.

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(User.class)
                 .add(Restrictions.eq(<column to check>, new Int(1)));
```

My confusion is whether to use the "**status_id**" or the "**statusId**" in the column to check for the criteria. I searched for the explanation and couldn't find similar problem. Can someone help me out in this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use the bean property name.  If your column is **status_id** and you have `int statusId` in your class, the property name for the criteria is the name of the bean property: **statusId**

This generates SQL and will figure out your query needs to be **status_id**

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/criterion/Restrictions.html

Answer (score 3):

```
@Column(name = "DEPT_NAME", length = 100)

private String DEPTNAME;
```

Here **DEPT_NAME** is supposed to be used when using **native sql**

**DEPTNAME** is used when using **HQL** and during **criteria**.

Answer (score 0):

Use statusId. You always use field names from the mapped POJOS and not the table column names unless you are trying to write a SQL.